# Why sed add a 0 in my substitution?

Tags: sed

I want to substitute this variable, with the value of "5.6.10"

```
VERSION=5.4.38
```

I know how to do if I known the current value (5.4.38)

```
sed s:VERSION=5.4.38:VERSION=5.6.10:g
```

But I want to substitute with the content of 5.6.10
even if I don't know the value(useful with many files or on script).
I have tried this

```
sed s:VERSION=[0-9].[0-9].[0-90-9]:VERSION=5.6.10:g
```

But the result is strange

```
VERSION=5.6.100
```

Why 10 became 100?

I have also tried

```
sed s:VERSION=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]:VERSION=5.6.10:g
```

And I see same result.

Comment: With `awk`: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1=="VERSION"{$2="5.6.10"; print}'` Set input and output field separator to `=`. If first column contains `VERSION` set second column to `5.6.10` and print row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[0-90-9]` matches one character, which may be any digit. You meant `[0-9][0-9]` to match exactly two digits. In both attempts, the last digit of `5.6.100` was not matched by the regular expression and so it's present, unchanged, in the output.

Another potential problem is that `.` is a special character in regular expressions: it matches any character. For example `[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]` matches `123.45` or `1a2b34`. Use `\.` to match a dot: a backslash before a special character makes it non-special.

Furthermore a version number may have more or fewer digits. Use `[0-9.]*` to match any number of dots or digits. (`.` is not a special character when it's inside brackets.) More precisely, `[0-9.]*` matches the longest possible sequence of dots and digits, so it'll match all of them. Use `[0-9][0-9.]*` if you want to enforce that there's at least one digit at the beginning.

```
sed 's:VERSION=[0-9][0-9.]*:VERSION=5.6.10:g'
```

Comment: further furthermore, you added quoting which wasn't present in the original, avoiding potential shell globbing.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you properly quote your `sed` expression so that the shell does not expand it as a filename globbing pattern, your command

```
sed 's:VERSION=[0-9].[0-9].[0-90-9]:VERSION=5.6.10:g'
```

would turn the string `VERSION=5.4.38` into `VERSION=5.6.108` (not `VERSION=5.6.100`).  It does this because `[0-90-9]` matches a *single* character.  It therefore replaces `VERSION=5.4.3` by `VERSION=5.6.10`, leaving the trailing `8` alone.

Other oddities in your `sed` substitution includes not escaping the dots (these would match any single character), and using `/g` at the end even though you're not expecting to match more than one string an any onel line as far as I can tell.

To replace a pattern on the form `VERSION=xx.yy.zz` where the `xx` etc. can be any string of digits, use

```
sed 's/\(VERSION=\)[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}/\15.6.10/'
```

or, if you want to use `[0-9]` instead of `[[:digit:]]`:

```
sed 's/\(VERSION=\)[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}/\15.6.10/'
```

or, if you want to use extended rather than basic regular expressions,

```
sed -E 's/(VERSION=)[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/\15.6.10/'
```

or, if you want to compress it further,

```
sed -E 's/(VERSION=)([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+/\15.6.10/'
```

or, indeed,

```
sed 's/\(VERSION=\).*/\15.6.10/'
```

... if all you need is to strip whatever follows `VERSION=` from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found adding a dot.
This work for 5.5.10, 6.4.20, 3.2.20,etc

```
sed s:VERSION=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].:VERSION=5.6.10:g
```

But not for 1.2.3 4.5.1 3.2.9
For this pairs this line works fine

```
sed s:VERSION=[0-9].[0-9].*.:VERSION=5.6.10:g
```

Comment: A `.` in a regex matches any character (including the literal `.`). If you want to match a literal `.`, you need to escape it as `\.`.
If you don't care about the value, why not use `sed 's/VERSION=.*/VERSION=5.6.10/'`?